# Using display:none in combination with nth-of-type and/or nth-child

Tags: css

I'd like to use the `:nth-of-type(even)` pseudo-class to create two even column panels in the web app I'm working on. I've re-created the problem in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sYWbR/

Essentially, the problem is that `display:none` is being treated like `visibility:hidden` when used in combination with the `:nth-of-type` or `:nth-child` pseudo-classes. Never run into this before.

Does `:nth-of-type` do its counting before `display:none` is applied? If that's the case, that kind of minimizes its helpfulness, as far as I'm concerned. Any workarounds?

Comment: What browser are you using? Chrome shows it as expected with display:none;

Comment: The pseudo-classes `:nth-child()`, `:nth-of-type()` and their first/last counterparts all count based on DOM structure. The DOM, or an element's placement in it, is not affected by any style rules that may get applied. Contrary to popular belief, setting an element's `display` style to `none` *does not remove the element from the DOM*.

Comment: @BoltClock: People think `display: none` removes it from the DOM?

Comment: @alex: Yeah, I've seen multiple people say that around here. They assume that since `display: none` takes an element away from document flow altogether, it must mean it doesn't exist in the DOM anymore either.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I think I was confusing display:none removing an element from the document flow, rather than removing it from the DOM. Make sense, thanks.